# Can't make Ionic Deeplinks working

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, deep-linking

I can't make Ionic Deeplinks working. I get this error. (I installed the https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native).

Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionic.native due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ionic.native' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

```
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic.native', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova', 'imageCropper','ngStorage'])

  .run(['$ionicPlatform', '$cordovaDeeplinks', '$state', '$timeout', function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaDeeplinks, $state, $timeout) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {

      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

      }
      if (window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleLightContent();
      }

      $cordovaDeeplinks.route({
        '/profile': {
          target: 'tab.profile',
          parent: 'tab-profile'
        }


      }).subscribe(function(match) {

        $timeout(function() {
          $state.go(match.$route.parent, match.$args);

          $timeout(function() {
            $state.go(match.$route.target, match.$args);
          }, 800);
        }, 100); // Timeouts can be tweaked to customize the feel of the deeplink
      }, function(nomatch) {
        console.warn('No match', nomatch);
      });
    });

  }])

  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I tried what you say but I still have the same message. Might I have to install something else?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run:

```
bower install ionic-native --save
```